# Compatible Version of Installshield for vb6?

Tags: deployment, vb6, installshield

I Have **InstallShield version-16**.
But its **not compatible** with **vb6**.
I googled a lot but i not able to figure out which version is **compatible** with **vb6**.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compatible with VB6"?  Installshield can deploy VB6 applications by dropping files into folders and registering COM components.

Answer (score 1):

InstallShield v16 is InstallShield 2010.   The VB6 virtual machine has been included in Windows for 10+ years now.  If you are looking at a recent service pack of XP, Vista, 7, 8, Server 2008/R2 et al  you are fine.

InstallShield handles COM extraction so I can't think of what you base your assertion that it's not "compatible with vb6".  You should be fine.

Comment: Even if you had to install the VB 6 runtime, InstallShield could do that too.

Answer (score 0):

One version of InstallShield comes packaged with Visual Studio 6. You may try to grab a genuine copy of Visual Studio 6 and use InstallShield from there.

Or try some setup creating applications available in the market.